# Eclipse in debug mode do not show variable content?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am not sure if it is recent issue or it was from the "beginning". Is it normal behavior that  we can't see the value of variable in debug mode when we tick on it? (It says ctr+shift+I to watch).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ctrl + shift + D to display the selected content.
Whatever you are trying to get the contents debug should reach that code.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't normal behaviour in Eclipse. As soon as a thread hits a breakpoint and enables the debugging perspective, you should be able to inspect your variables either by hovering, Ctrl+Shift+I or with "Inspect" in your context menu.

In what state is Eclipse when you are trying to watch the variable?